# Indexing by ROW on a Column and finding partial matches in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I am having issues developing a for loop that incorporates a partial match feature.

To breakdown the problem:

I have two sheets that are going to be compared - one exists on sheet1 column b and the other sheet2 column c.

The for loop will iterate through column B on Sheet1 and then extract the current string at each row - this current string is then passed *I tried vlookup* and compared to the ENTIRE column C on sheet 2 to find a match: if there is a match it will then return the ADJACENT column to the right of Column C and then Deposit this value to the ADJACENT Column to the right of Column B.

I have currently tried implementing a for if statement that iterates through Column b and if the current string of Column B is equal to a Vlookup of Column C for the match on Current string then return the value.

```
Sub JoinGroupOnPN()
Dim PartGroupSheet As Worksheet
Dim OEEPartSheet As Worksheet    
Dim OEERowRange As Long    
Dim OEEColumnRange As Long    
Dim PGRowRange As Long    
Dim PGColumnRange As Long    
Dim OEEArray As Variant    
Dim PGArray As Variant    
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set PartGroupSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PartGroup")    
Set OEEPartSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OEE Report")    
OEERowRange = OEEPartSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    
OEEColumnRange = OEEPartSheet.Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Row    
PGRowRange = PartGroupSheet.Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    
PGColumnRange = PartGroupSheet.Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Row
ReDim OEEArray(OEERowRange, OEEColumnRange)    
ReDim PGArray(PGRowRange, PGColumnRange)    
Dim StringToMatch As String    
Dim MatchingString As String

For i = 2 To OEERowRange
StringToMatch = OEEPartSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text
MatchingString = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Arg1:=StringToMatch, Arg2:=PartGroupSheet.Range(Cell1:=2, Cell2:=1), Arg3:=2, Arg4:=True)

    For j = 2 To PGRowRange

        If StringToMatch = MatchingString Then

            Debug.Print StringToMatch

        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I keep getting an error that says the range object failed and I have tried converting it to a range type but still same error.

The Error happens at

```
MatchingString = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Arg1:=StringToMatch, Arg2:=PartGroupSheet.Range(Cell1:=2, Cell2:=1), Arg3:=2, Arg4:=True)
```

and the error message is Method 'Range' of 'Object'_WorkSheet Failed

I cant post any pictures yet

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GOqP.png)
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwhER.png)

Any help would be appreciated thanks !!

Comment: As always, if you're getting an error, please include the text of the error and let folks know on which line it occurs.

Comment: `PartGroupSheet.Range(Cell1:=2, Cell2:=1)` is not a valid table reference.  VLookup is not that good with partial matches, so it may not even be useful here.  If you add some sample data showing the types of values you're trying to match that would be useful.

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated the post with the relevant info - thanks for the help I apologize about my sloppy posting. Hope the pictures help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub JoinGroupOnPN()
    Dim PartGroupSheet As Worksheet
    Dim v, c As Range, rngSrch As Range

    Set PartGroupSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PartGroup")

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OEE Report")
        Set rngSrch = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each c In rngSrch.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            'do not use WorksheetFunction here
            v = Application.VLookup(c.Value, PartGroupSheet.Range("B:C"), 2, False)
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(IsError(v), "No match", v)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, you are a legend. Thank you very much, I can't seem to wrap my head around the syntax coming from Python but I digress.

Cheers,