# Finding A Matching String with VLookup then Return Columns at Row Index

Tags: excel, vba

Building off an earlier StackOverflow question I posted: [Indexing by ROW on a Column and finding partial matches in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369928/indexing-by-row-on-a-column-and-finding-partial-matches-in-a-string/56370101#56370101)

I am creating  a variation of this but where the string matches - Copy the entire row (A1:C1) for example then insert at the next empty row spot in a new sheet.

```
Sub PeopleFilter()
' Defining Workbook and Worksheets to be used
Dim PeopleWorkbook As Workbook
Dim People As Worksheet
Dim UnitedKingdom, UnitedStates, Canada As Worksheet
' Letting our Variables equal something
Set PeopleWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set People = PeopleWorkbook.Worksheets("People")
Set UnitedKingdom = PeopleWorkbook.Worksheets("United Kingdom")
Set UnitedStates = PeopleWorkbook.Worksheets("United States")
Set Canada = PeopleWorkbook.Worksheets("Canada")
' Defining ranges
Dim PeopleDataRange As Range
' C1 is cell 1 - C2, cell 2
Dim C1 As Range
Dim C2 As Range
' Equating C1 to the cell that is at the 2nd row first column
' Equating C2 to the cell that is at the last row position first column
Set C1 = People.Cells(2, 1)
Set C2 = People.Cells(People.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)
' Creating a range out of these two cells
Set PeopleDataRange = People.Range(C1, C2)
' Printing length of Range
Debug.Print PeopleDataRange.Count
' For each row
Dim ThisWorks As Boolean

For Each c In PeopleDataRange.Rows
        If People.Rows(c, 2).Value = "United States" Then
            ThisWorks = True
        Else
            ThisWorks = False
        End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I am currently just debugging this - that is why it doesn't actually do anything aside from changing the value of a boolean. I am getting an error at

If People.Rows(c, 2).Value = "United States" Then
Error Code: 1004 - Application or Object Defined Error

The workflow should be as follows - Index through column searching for specific string match, once found - copy a selection of columns.

IE If a string match is found on Row 35 - Return Row 35 column A,b,c,d... to a new sheet.

[Main Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tspIW.png)

[Sheet to have data inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9I2D.png)

*Edit - The Expected results should be as the loop iterates each time - the boolean value should turn true when the value matches the lookup

1:True
2:False
3:True
4:False
5:False
6:False *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is not a row number but a range containing the cell in column A.  You need to refer to the row:

```
If People.cells(c.row, 2).Value = "United States" Then
```

Comment: One more quick thing - When I try to add a list of criteria such as 
If People.Cells(c.Row, 2).Value = Array(Canada" | "United Kingdom") then

I get a type mismatch error - How would I say if the string value is either equal to this or that

Comment: You cannot equate a value to an array.  you will need to do two test with `Or`

Comment: Thanks for the help Scott. I incorporated the or into the if statement and got desired output

Comment: @AdrianHudson when you get an answer to your question you should mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.